# Driving a rental car accross the Croatia-Montenegro border and back

Tags: europe, international-travel, car-rentals, montenegro, dubrovnik

While I will be based in Dubrovnik, I want to see Kotor in Montenegro. Some buses do the route from one to the other but there seems to be plenty of interesting things along the bay and I also want to explore these on my own schedule.

Ideally, I am looking for a car rental agency in Dubrovnik which rents an automatic car (I'm from Canada, never learned standard) and lets me take it across the border and come back to return the car in Dubrovnik.

Does anyone know of such a rental place? Is that possible? If not, maybe there is a car rental place near the border between Croatia and Montenegro and I could use a bus or taxi to bridge the gap. This would be least preferred.

Comment: I recommend autoeurope.com or the German rental car firm Sixt. No affiliation with them, but I used both with perfect results. I've also done a transborder (within EU) rental with Avis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are car rental agencies at the airport. Among them Sixt allows to cross into Montenegro for an extra fee of 6 EUR. They also significantly raise the insurance premium which probably depends on the car, for a compact automatic it was 30 EUR per day.

Answer (score 4):

In general car hires in europe will let you cross country lines, at least within the EU (which unfortunatley Montenegro is not). However, you should confirm this with the hire company - either through reading policies on their website, or by asking them. You've got two issues to be concerned with - firstly whether the hire company's insurance applies once you cross the border and secondly whether the car you are hiring is legal to drive in the new country.

Comment: In my experience, it is at least sometimes the case that you can pay an additional fee (presumably for insurance) if you want to take the car to another country.